# WampServer Deprecated functions with X-Cart

Tags: php5

I want to run my X-Cart website on my own local Wampserver, to trial if updating the X-Cart server breaks the website or not.  The X-Cart version is 4.2.2.

When I run it on localhost, I receive the following error before the main content:

```
( ! ) Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\hilla\prepare.php on line 52
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0362  380720  {main}( )   ..\home.php:0
2   0.0497  392656  require( 'C:\wamp\www\hilla\auth.php' ) ..\home.php:38
3   0.0713  399144  require( 'C:\wamp\www\hilla\preauth.php' )  ..\auth.php:45
4   0.0899  650648  include_once( 'C:\wamp\www\hilla\init.php' )    ..\preauth.php:51
5   0.0957  878200  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\hilla\prepare.php' ) ..\init.php:41

Error: Smarty error: [in customer/home.tpl line 18]: syntax error: unrecognized tag 'var' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 590) in C:\wamp\www\hilla\include\lib\smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1092
```

The local WampServer has Apache Version: 2.2.17, PHP Version: 5.3.5  .

Does this mean *set_magic_quotes_runtime()* does not work with PHP v5.3.5 or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Means that the functions is decprecated so in PHP 5.3 she is included but in PHP6 not.

The Problem is that the warning makes an output when you disable the despricated messages in your php.ini the system should work.

Comment: @Stony - thanks. How do I disable deprecated messages in php.ini?

Comment: @Steve: error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED

Comment: @Stony.  Made that change, restarted the server, and the error remains.  ?

Comment: @Steve have you looked that you have error_reporting only one time in the php.ini activated. In most cased there is a second value in the buttom of the file.

Comment: @Stony: I found a second instance and added ~E_DEPRECATED, but the error remains.  I found no other instances.

Comment: @Steve i think the last problem is that the error_reporting is set in your application? Search for error_reporting in your X-Cart app perhapts there is error_reporting(E_ALL).

Comment: @Stony.  Thanks; there was: 
if ($debug_mode)
 $x_error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE;
else
 $x_error_reporting = 0;